# R matchit on 7 variables with different seeds

Tags: r, matching, random-seed

I am using the following code to match 2 cohorts (2800 controls, 460 treated) of different patients:

```
set.seed(99)
m.out <- matchit(treatment ~ gender + age + VarC + diseaseDuration + 
                 pastActivity + activity + country, data = Pat.match, 
                 method = "nearest", ratio = 5, discard = "control", 
                 caliper = 0.1, m.order = "smallest")
```

After matching, the cohorts are reduced to about 1230 controls vs. 400 treated.
These numbers are similar when I change the seed. However, if I check more accurately (patient ID), the total cohorts for different seeds differ in about 20% of the patients. To be more precise:
set.seed(99) results in a cohort, that has an overlap of only 80% with the resulting cohort of set.seed(27).
And this might have a huge impact on further general models and statistical analyses. Have I overseen something ?
Regards !

Comment: Please specify which package you are sourcing `matchit()` from.

Comment: I'm using
`library(MatchIt)`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this occurs when units have the same or very similar propensity scores; I believe MatchIt resolves this with a randomly selected match. I actually disagree with @dash2 that you shouldn't change the seed until you get a result you like. You should perform the matching procedure as many times as you want until you arrive at covariate balance. If your data is balanced and all your treated units are retained (or at least the same ones across matching specifications), then your effect estimation will not vary systematically with your matched set. Just remember that once you have estimated your treatment effect, you can't go back and redo your matching results (which is probably what @dash2 is getting at). But at the matching phase, this is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

So the computing side of this is that matchit is probably doing something random, even though you haven't e.g. specified `m.order="random"`. What that could be, it's probably easiest to find out by looking through the source code...

The statistical side is really for crossvalidated, not here, but I would suggest:

- if any of your results depend non-trivially on the seed, don't trust the results, they are not robust.
- in particular - I'm sure you know this but it is worth reiterating - do NOT try different seeds until you get a result you like!

Comment: Thank you dash2. Yes, I know that `matchit` has some random effect whilst using `caliper!=0` which is expected. But I didn't expect that this would result in such big differences when you are matching on 7 variables.

Comment: Question is, does it result in big differences in terms of the quantities of interest?